# how can save DateTime c# language to oracle10g database

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle10g

there is a table== create table newstudent(enroll int, name varchar2(20), DoJoin date);
in c# when i type

```
oraclecommand(1,'amit purohit', DateTime.Now());
//Error found 'nvalid month'
oraclecommand(1,'amit purohit', String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}"));
//problme that save only date into database but i need time also. like '11-AUG-2009 11:22:32.0'
oraclecommand(1,'amit purohit', String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss}")
//also error get like string picture format in date time values
```

Comment: Well we've no idea what "oraclecommand" is. What you've posted isn't valid C# anyway, as 'amit purohit' isn't a valid string (wrong quotes). Please post *actual code*. Ideally, post a short but complete program (e.g. a console app) which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3):

One of your problems may be the fact that your date is in the wrong format for Oracle.

Oracle accepts the **yyyy/mm/dd** date format which I can see you're not using.

I'm with Jon Skeet on this one for the oraclecommand but you maybe want to try creating a normal SQL Query inside a string and then running the query.

You can use the to_date function to convert your date into the correct format.

```
insert into table_name
(date_field)
values
(to_date('2003/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

(Via [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_date.php))

Or on the other hand you may try converting the date to a proper Oracle accepted format using some C# functions: [Oracle/PLSQL: Insert a date/time value into an Oracle table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a parameterized statement, and add a parameter with the relevant data in, specifying the appropriate parameter type. The exact format of that will depend on which Oracle driver you're using, but it's likely to be something like:

```
command.Parameters.Add(":date", OracleDbType.DateTime).Value = ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (non-tested code):

```
public void InsertDateTime(DateTime aoDateTime) {
  using (var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection("<my connection string>")) 
  {
    var oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(
      "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (MY_DATE_FIELD) VALUES (:pMY_DATE_VALUE)", 
      oracleConnection);
    oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(
      new OracleParameter(":pMY_DATE_VALUE", aoDateTime));

    oracleConnection.Open();
    oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [standard date format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Comment: You should not convert your DateTime to string before inserting it to database. It's not necessary nor a good practice.